# Magento 2 admin panel not working after ssl

Tags: admin, magento2.2.2, ssl

I have an error that maybe someone can help with.

> This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.

After i went live with my magento 2.2.2 everthing went smoothly, after that installed SSL certicate and went into maintainance mode (of course excluding my ip)
Basically my admin rewrite/redirects for https are not working, and I can't access the admin panel, front-end working fine btw.

### Browser spits out this message.

The page isn't redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.

---

**Note :** Rewrite engine is on from htacces and conf. so....

Answer (score 3):

You can try modifying core_config_data and removing the cache. Follow these steps:

1. Open the database of your Magento store
2. Find core_config_data.
3. Use this SQL query:

INSERTINTO core_config_data (scope,scope_id,path,value) VALUES ('default',0,'web/secure/use_in_adminhtml',1);

4. Finally, remove the cache by deleting /var/cache.

If it doesn't work, you can try changing the URL back to default. You can find the process to do it [right here](https://hostadvice.com/how-to/how-to-solve-the-10-most-common-magento-ssl-issues/).

Comment: It works for me. Thank you!